# Bijective mapping to fixed image set

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I need to reduce the amount of stored data in an Ethereum Smart Contract. Currently I am storing $n < 2^8$ strings in a mapping (i.e. a map data structure) and each string is mapped into $[0, n)$; since this uses up to much memory, I'm looking for ways to compute the mapping instead of reading it from storage.

I've looked into [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), but it creates big numbers and I have no clue how I can change the image set to $[0, n)$.

---

The strings have a length of 2 to 7 and consist of capital letters, numbers, and dashes.

Comment: Would Huffman Coding be applicable to the data?

Comment: @CyclotomicField The set of possible characters has a fixed size, so it would be possible.